# why I keep getting "Fatal error: Call to undefined function getCountries()" in php oop?

Tags: php

I am beginner in php OOP but I have created a class called countries as the following:

countries.php

```
class countries {
    public $countries = array("Afghanistan","Hong Kong","Moldova","Malawi");

    public function getCountries() {
         return $countries;
    }
}
```

test.php

```
require_once('/lbs/countries.php'); 
$country = new countries();

print_r($country->{getCountries()});
```

Comment: because `getCountries()` is not defined (well that's my guess) :)

Comment: Why do you have curly braces around the method `{getCountries()}`?

Comment: what is the true way to define it getCountries()? :)

Comment: If you remove the curly braces, it works (you also want to replace `$countries` with `$this->countries` in your method). https://3v4l.org/lXOEQ

Comment: Side note, accessor functions like your `getCountries` are most often used to access private or protected properties. In your case, the `countries` property is already accessible with `$country->countries` because it is public, so that method isn't actually necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change it, use `$this->` if you don't call static function or variable. In your situation to get array values with `$this->`

```
public function getCountries() {
   return $this->countries;
}
```

and also call function from class without - {braces}, for instance, `$class->function_name();`

```
print_r($country->getCountries());
```

Comment: A function inside a class is called method.